# How to solve out Green's function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I am studying the Scattering theory by John R. Taylor but I met a mathematic problem in Section 11-h.

$\phi_{lp}(r)$ is the solution of radial Schoedinger equation:

$$
\Big[\frac{d^2}{dr^2}-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}+p^2\Big]\phi_{lp}(r)=U(r)\phi_{lp}(r)
$$

with the boundary condition: $\phi_{lp}(0)=0.$ The corresponding Green's function is:

$$
\Big[\frac{d^2}{dr^2}-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}+p^2\Big]g_{lp}(r,r')=\delta(r-r')
$$

The particular solution is:
$$\phi_{lp}(r)=\int dr'g_{lp}(r,r')U(r')\phi_{lp}(r')$$

The boundary condition of Green's function is also: $g_{lp}(0,r')=0.$ How can I solve out this Green's function?

Comment: What's the boundary condition at infinity?

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks for your reply. I use method of variation parameter to get an answer without boundary condition at infinity. That is weird....